# Scaling difficulty of landing a rocket

Tags: dimensional-analysis, rocket-science, order-of-magnitude

I am wondering whether it is more difficult to land (as spaceX does) a rocket of height $k L$ than landing a rocket of height $L$? Is there some scaling law? Or at least is there a way to see in the equations the influence of the height of the rocket?

I would accept any interesting reasoning about this problem, I would also take any link to books/internet, because this may be classical, although I did not find anything.

By "landing a rocket" I mean "actively control the direction of the rocket, so that it is sufficiently upright to land".

I know this is somewhat a vague question, but I expect that this falls into the dimensional analysis / order of magnitude sections.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If all of the dimensions of the rocket are scaled by a factor of $k$ then its weight will change by a factor of $k^3$ but the lever arm of steering jets mounted on the nose or tail of the rocket will change by a factor of $k$. So a scale factor $k>1$ will make it more difficult to keep the rocket vertical - the force exerted by the steering jets must increase by a factor of $k^2$.

However, if only the length of the rocket is scaled by a factor of $k$ then weight and lever arm both change by the same factor, so the difficulty of keeping the rocket upright should remain the same.

Comment: "the force exerted by the steering jets must increase by a factor of $k^2$": note that the area available at the base for engines increases by the same factor. Also note that the disturbing forces are affected by the change in dimensions as well.